# is there a more efficient version of pygame.key.get_pressed(pygame.K)

Tags: python, function, pygame

This is a part of my alphabet in my pygame code.
It works perfectly fine, but takes up alot of lines and looks ugly. its also not portable.
Ive tried to create a function for it that can add the letter to any variable, not just "username" in my case but haven't succeeded.

```py
event_list = pygame.event.get()

for event in event_list:

    pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if pressed[pygame.K_a]:
        username += "a"
    if pressed[pygame.K_b]:
        username += "b"
    if pressed[pygame.K_c]:
        username += "c"
    # ....... etc etc
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how i can turn this into a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyboard events `KEYDOWN` and `KEYUP` (see [pygame.event](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) module) create a [`pygame.event.Event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.Event) object with additional attributes. The key that was pressed can be obtained from the `key` attribute (e.g. `K_RETURN` , `K_a`) and the `mod` attribute contains a bitset with additional modifiers (e.g. `KMOD_LSHIFT`). The `unicode` attribute provides the Unicode representation of the keyboard input.

e.g.:

```py
def input_text(event_list, name):
    
    finished = False
    for event in event_list:
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
       
            if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                finished = True
            else:
                name += event.unicode

    return (finished, name)
```

Call the `input_text` function in the application loop:

```py
username = ""
password = ""
current_input = "username"

run = True
while run:
    event_list = pygame.event.get()
    for event in event_list:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    if current_input == "username":
        finished, username = input_text(event_list, username)
        if finished:
            current_input = "password"

    elif current_input == "password":
        finished, password = input_text(event_list, password)
        if finished:
            current_input = ""
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily get the name of the pressed key:

```py
for event in event_list:
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        name = pygame.key.name(event.key)
        if len(name) == 1:  #  Check if it is a character
            username += pygame.key.name(event.key)
```